# Run second javascript script after first one is completed - animated text effect

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this futuristic style text effect and would like to create effect like this:

First it should animated  phrase:

*Test phrase*

After that adds a word after this phrase, like:

*dog
cat*

So the end phrase would be:

*Test phrase dog*

or

*Test phrase cat*

First phrase would animate only once, and second would interchange, showing dog first, then cat, and repeat.

I currently found a workaround by using CSS to make the second phrase appear after some time but it's not an ideal situation. Is it possible to set it in JavaScript?

Additionally, for some reason second phrase, when it appears at first, it doesn't have the space before it, making it like:

*Test phrasecat*

What could be the reason for this?

```js
// Futuristic Resolving/Typing Text Effect
// Copyright (c) by Kevin (https://codepen.io/qkevinto/pen/WQVNWO)
// License (MIT): https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/

var resolver = {
  resolve: function resolve(options, callback) {
    // The string to resolve
    var resolveString = options.resolveString || options.element.getAttribute('data-target-resolver');
    var combinedOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { resolveString: resolveString });

    function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    function randomCharacter(characters) {
      return characters[getRandomInteger(0, characters.length - 1)];
    };

    function doRandomiserEffect(options, callback) {
      var characters = options.characters;
      var timeout = options.timeout;
      var element = options.element;
      var partialString = options.partialString;

      var iterations = options.iterations;

      setTimeout(function () {
        if (iterations >= 0) {
          var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { iterations: iterations - 1 });

          // Ensures partialString without the random character as the final state.
          if (iterations === 0) {
            element.textContent = partialString;
          } else {
            // Replaces the last character of partialString with a random character
            element.textContent = partialString.substring(0, partialString.length - 1) + randomCharacter(characters);
          }

          doRandomiserEffect(nextOptions, callback);
        } else if (typeof callback === "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }, options.timeout);
    };

    function doResolverEffect(options, callback) {
      var resolveString = options.resolveString;
      var characters = options.characters;
      var offset = options.offset;
      var partialString = resolveString.substring(0, offset);
      var combinedOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { partialString: partialString });

      doRandomiserEffect(combinedOptions, function () {
        var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { offset: offset + 1 });

        if (offset <= resolveString.length) {
          doResolverEffect(nextOptions, callback);
        } else if (typeof callback === "function") {
          callback();
        }
      });
    };

    doResolverEffect(combinedOptions, callback);
  }


  /* Some GLaDOS quotes from Portal 2 chapter 9: The Part Where He Kills You
     * Source: http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/GLaDOS_voice_lines#Chapter_9:_The_Part_Where_He_Kills_You
     */ };
var strings = [
'Test phrase '];


var counter = 0;

var options = {
  // Initial position
  offset: 0,
  // Timeout between each random character
  timeout: 5,
  // Number of random characters to show
  iterations: 10,
  // Random characters to pick from
  characters: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'x', '#', '%', '&', '-', '+', '_', '?', '/', '\\', '='],
  // String to resolve
  resolveString: strings[counter],
  // The element
  element: document.querySelector('[data-target-resolver]')


  // Callback function when resolve completes
};function callback() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    counter++;

    if (counter >= strings.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { resolveString: strings[counter] });
    resolver.resolve(nextOptions, callback);
  }, 100000000);
}

resolver.resolve(options, callback);




// Futuristic Resolving/Typing Text Effect
// Copyright (c) by Kevin (https://codepen.io/qkevinto/pen/WQVNWO)
// License: (MIT) https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/


var resolver = {
  resolve: function resolve(options, callback) {
    // The string to resolve
    var resolveString = options.resolveString || options.element.getAttribute('data-target-resolver2');
    var combinedOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { resolveString: resolveString });

    function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    function randomCharacter(characters) {
      return characters[getRandomInteger(0, characters.length - 1)];
    };

    function doRandomiserEffect(options, callback) {
      var characters = options.characters;
      var timeout = options.timeout;
      var element = options.element;
      var partialString = options.partialString;

      var iterations = options.iterations;

      setTimeout(function () {
        if (iterations >= 0) {
          var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { iterations: iterations - 1 });

          // Ensures partialString without the random character as the final state.
          if (iterations === 0) {
            element.textContent = partialString;
          } else {
            // Replaces the last character of partialString with a random character
            element.textContent = partialString.substring(0, partialString.length - 1) + randomCharacter(characters);
          }

          doRandomiserEffect(nextOptions, callback);
        } else if (typeof callback === "function") {
          callback();
        }
      }, options.timeout);
    };

    function doResolverEffect(options, callback) {
      var resolveString = options.resolveString;
      var characters = options.characters;
      var offset = options.offset;
      var partialString = resolveString.substring(0, offset);
      var combinedOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { partialString: partialString });

      doRandomiserEffect(combinedOptions, function () {
        var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { offset: offset + 1 });

        if (offset <= resolveString.length) {
          doResolverEffect(nextOptions, callback);
        } else if (typeof callback === "function") {
          callback();
        }
      });
    };

    doResolverEffect(combinedOptions, callback);
  }


  /* Some GLaDOS quotes from Portal 2 chapter 9: The Part Where He Kills You
     * Source: http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/GLaDOS_voice_lines#Chapter_9:_The_Part_Where_He_Kills_You
     */ };
var strings = [
'cat',
'dog'];


var counter = 0;

var options = {
  // Initial position
  offset: 0,
  // Timeout between each random character
  timeout: 5,
  // Number of random characters to show
  iterations: 10,
  // Random characters to pick from
  characters: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'x', '#', '%', '&', '-', '+', '_', '?', '/', '\\', '='],
  // String to resolve
  resolveString: strings[counter],
  // The element
  element: document.querySelector('[data-target-resolver2]')


  // Callback function when resolve completes
};function callback() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    counter++;

    if (counter >= strings.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    var nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, { resolveString: strings[counter] });
    resolver.resolve(nextOptions, callback);
  }, 3000);
  // }, 3000);
}

// setTimeout(resolver.resolve(options, callback), 5000);
resolver.resolve(options, callback);
```

```css
.second-line {
      -webkit-animation: appear 2.5s ease-out;
              animation: appear 2.5s ease-out; }

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }
```

```html
<h1><span data-target-resolver></span><span data-target-resolver2 c class="second-line"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the space issue, you could add a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) between the `span`s and remove/ignore the space in the script.

For the chaining of function calls (1=resolve "Test phrase", 2=resolve "Cat", etc) you could put your `resolve` call for resolving 2 inside the callback function of 1 (`resolver.resolve(options, callback)`). This will get called after the first sentence is done animating. (And remove the CSS animation entirely.)